# How can I load an OpenSeadragon component in my Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, openseadragon

I have to use an external javascript library in my Vue Component, named "`OpenSeadragon`".

But how can I load this component in my Vue component?
In my parent template I load the library with:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/openseadragon.min.js') }}"></script>
```

This is my **Vue TestComponent**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="openseadragon" style="width: 100%; height: 600px; border: 1px solid red"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        data(){
            return {

            }
        },
        created() {

           // How can I load openseadragon??
            OpenSeadragon({
                id:              "openseadragon",
                prefixUrl:       "/openseadragon/images/",
                tileSources:     "/example-images/duomo/duomo.dzi"
            });


        },
        methods: {
            //
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then I get this error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"

Comment: Do you get any error? What about it doesn't work?

Comment: I have updated my question with the error I get

Comment: @3142maple thanks! When I put this code in mounted() it works!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Vue Lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), you should put your function call in `mounted`.

Because the element `#openseadragon` doesn't exists before `mounted` is called.